# To log Lambda function name in cloudwatch

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is there any possible way to log the name of the Lambda in CloudWatch ?

Ex:

START RequestId: 4b453a3-f239-461f-94ab-ebesdfsdb04de Version: $LATEST

The "RequestId" is already getting logged. Any property I can use to log the name of the lambda as well ?

I don't want an explicit console.log statement but a property/parameter which directly gives out my lambda's name along with START , END and INFO fields.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using context property (function_name).

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("lambda function: {}".format(context.function_name))
```

Please refer below [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You coud use environment variable `AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME` (see [full list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-environment-variables.html)). If your Lambda are written on Python it could looks like this:

```
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Running function '%s'" % os.environ.get('AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME', None))
```

Answer (score 0):

could do this in nodejs

`console.log(process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME)`